# Upload paperclip images to s3 bucket

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

Not quite sure whats going on here, but when i try and upload an image to my s3 bucket i get this error

```
 NameError in PostsController#create

 uninitialized constant AWS::Core::ClientLogging

 Rails.root: /home/richardlewis/Rails/myblog
 Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

 app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:41:in `create'
```

Im testing this in my dev environment at present. This is my current setup

Gemfile

```
#Paperclip and aws
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'aws-s3'
```

Image Model

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

attr_accessible :photo
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small_blog => "250x250#", :large_blog => "680x224#", :thumb => "95x95#" },
 :storage => :s3,
 :url  => ":s3_domain_url",
 :s3_protocol => 'http',
 :path => "/images/:id/:style.:extension",
 :s3_credentials => {
 :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
 :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
 :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
}
end
```

My ENV variables are stored in a env.rb file and loaded within initializers

has anyone come across this before?

Comment: What versions of `aws-sdk` and `aws-s3` show up in your `bundle list`?

Comment: aws-sdk (1.11.1) and aws-s3 (0.6.3), also paperclip is (3.3.1). i have read that there could be some issues with versions but thought that these have been resolved now and updated in the gem?

Comment: ok so just to update @RyanBigg i have updated my paperclip version to latest (3.5.1) at this time and this has resolved the issue, source = https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest paperclip, `3.5.1`, will fix this issue.